# Getting the last insert of your table

Tags: format

I have a table RECEIPT and the ID that i created is

REC-201290001 = "REC-"+"YEAR"+"MONTH"+"0001"

I create the number with a String.Format but in order to create the next one i need the last ID i inserted so i can increase it.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Which flavor of database are you using?

Comment: .... what do you mean sorry i dont understand :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("select value from config where name = 'next_receipt_id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$receiptId = "REC-"+"YEAR"+"MONTH"+$row['value'];

$insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT into order (`id`,...) values($receiptId,...)");

$updateReceiptId = mysql_query("update config set value = value+1 where name = 'next_receipt_id');
```

Comment: Ho, then you'll need a persistent storage in a DB to hold the id.

Comment: Sorry if i dont understand.. but can you explain me what is persistent storage i just tried to google it but i dont get the definition....

Comment: what i would do is create a table config with columns `name`,`value` and insert `next_receipt_id`,`REC-201290001` then when you want to isnert a new receipt, you fetch from that table where name = 'next_receipt_id' you get the value, insert it in your table, then you increment the receipt_id and insert the new value in the config table.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of persistent storage for a counter. You generate fresh IDs using that counter as a seed.

You can use a simple file, or, more elegant, a database for the purpose of the persistent storage. There are hundreds of tutorials in the internet about this.

Comment: I have a database but not an specific table or column to storage the number... you think thats the best way to do it?...